A simple group with 3 generators
All finite simple groups are generated by two elements, though apparently the proof is tens of thousands of pages long. Here’s an obvious follow-up:
What’s an example of a finitely presentable simple group with 3 generators (and not 2)?

One natural question is to find a f.g. simple group generated by 3 but not 2 elements, another is to fine a finitely presentable one. But I don't immediately see the point of asking a "short finite presentation", especially to start with.

I don't know of a finitely presented (infinite) simple group that is definitively known to not be 2-generated, but there is a finitely generated simple group that is definitively not 2-generated (https://link.springer.com/article/10.1007/BF00969195) and a finitely presented (5 generators and 10 relations, so, pretty short) simple group in Corollary IV(ii) of (https://arxiv.org/pdf/1712.01091) that maybe someone who's good at computational manipulations could check whether or not it's 2-generated.

@MattZaremsky's references: Guba - A finitely generated simple group with free 2-generated subgroups and Radu - New simple lattices in products of trees and their projections.

@YCor: I asked it that way because I thought the problem was easy and would have a standard answer. If it’s harder I agree any finitely generated or presented not-2-generated simple group is interesting.

@GeoffreyIrving my point was also that you're not only asking about a finitely presentable group, but about an explicit (short) presentation.

Fair enough! Better now?

I think it’s still an open problem whether any of the Burger-Mozes simple groups are 2-generated (though “surely” they aren’t). However, the smallest known generating sets are quite large too.

I agree with the other commenters that this is an open problem. I recently learned about it from Francesco Fournier-Facio.

This is just a too-long comment.
Besides Burger-Mozes-style groups, the "main" source of finitely presented infinite simple groups is "Thompson-like groups" (Richard Thompson, not John Thompson, confusingly) and these tend to be 2-generated, often thanks to the following straightforward sufficient condition that's worth mentioning here for the record:
See Theorem 5.15 of Bleak-Elliott-Matucci's paper here ("Sufficient conditions for a group of homeomorphisms of the Cantor set to be two-generated", J. Inst. Math. Jussieu). This states that if you have a finitely generated simple group $G$ of homeomorphisms of Cantor space that is "vigorous", then $G$ is 2-generated. Vigorous means that for any clopen set $A$ properly containing clopen sets $B$ and $C$, some element of $G$ can move $B$ into $C$ without moving anything outside $A$.
So as soon as the group is finitely generated, simple, and can move stuff around sufficiently robustly, it's 2-generated. The classical finitely presented simple Thompson group $V$ is vigorous, as are various relatives of it. By the way, they also explicitly ask in Question 6.1 whether there exists a finitely presented simple group that is not 2-generated.

Note: "without moving anything outside $A$" means "fixing pointwise the complement of $A$" (I couldn't guess this, so I opened the paper).  Also $C$ has to be assumed nonempty otherwise the definition is absurd.

@YCor Oh yes, my phrasing was ambiguous, "fixing pointwise the complement of $A$" is right. And right, $C$ better be non-empty.

Unless you prefer otherwise, I’m tempted to accept this answer: it’s good intuition for why it’s open and hard.

@GeoffreyIrving Sure, I guess if someone ends up having a better answer then they'll have also solved a big open problem, so they can't be mad :-)
